# "fake_module: addon missing 'bl_info'" error when installing an add-on

Tags: add-on, linux

I am trying to install an addon to export models to [Minetest](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_9Omh3evOAhVJqB4KHc8jALkQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.minetest.net%2F&usg=AFQjCNFw7EJtoQCK_dN1VTRU0WVTnmsBWw&sig2=d8svDiwPN_7BmVnpkI1sLQ).
I tried installing the addon file: [B3DExport.py](https://github.com/RainWarrior/B3DExport), but I don't see it available inside Prefs/Addons from within Blender. Neither it is available when going in File/Export/ 
I have tried it both ways: 
Using the "install from file..." button), and 
by manually putting the file in the addons folder. 
Either way it won't show in the File/Export menu. For both .py files 
I am running Blender in Ubuntu Studio 16.04 btw. 
I have tried Blender 2.77, and 2.71. 
The only reason I tried 2.71 is because it was [recommended](http://wiki.minetest.net/Using_Blender) in the instructions to use Blender for Minetest.

Excerpt from the Terminal:

> fake_module: addon missing 'bl_info' gives bad performance!: '/home/javier/.config/blender/2.77/scripts/addons/B3DExport.py'
>   Modules Installed from '/home/javier/Applications/blender-2.77a/B3DExport.py' into '/home/javier/.config/blender/2.77/scripts/addons' ()

Comment: the error you are getting implies the addon is missing the bl_info dictionary, which the source in the link clearly has.  Saving the file in my addons folder It works fine for me using blender 2.77.3 ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: Thanks for the info batFINGER. Then the conclusion is... reinstall Blender?

Comment: This is odd: I just installed another add-on (Blendermada). Even though this one did install successfully, it also gives that same error:

found bundled python: /home/javier/Applications/blender-2.77a/2.77/python
fake_module: addon missing 'bl_info' gives bad performance!: '/home/javier/.config/blender/2.77/scripts/addons/B3DExport.py'
addon_utils.disable: blendermada not disabled.
Modules Installed from '/home/javier/Applications/blendermada.py' into '/home/javier/.config/blender/2.77/scripts/addons' (blendermada)

Comment: Not sure what is going on for you with that.  Recently been emulating, to some degree, addon code for submods of an addon.  The bl_info is a dictionary of details in the addon module. The fake_module is using importlib.import_module (or `__import__`) to load the addons  which checks that it has a bl_info dic, if there isn't one you get the error you've outlined.  Can you look at the source of the .py files concerned in your .config/.../addons folder and check that the bl_info is there... be something like bl_info = {"description":"Blah",....}.

Comment: Finally got around to check the script... and I'm so so so glad you suggested it! Somehow it had more HTML & CSS tags/coding than it had Python coding. 
The solution was: 
1. Avoid right-clicking on the add-on file link, to choose "Save link as...".
2. And just click on the same link so that it shows its code. Then copy all the code into a non-formatted text file, and change its extension to .py